# Efficient pythonic way to snap a value to some grid

Tags: python, performance, algorithm

I have a one-dimensional grid that is defined as a list of sorted floating point values. The points are not equidistant, but it is guaranteed that there is no any pair of clashing points (distance==0).

I need to find the most efficient way to snap any given value to the closest grid point. The most clever way I could think of was as follows (`np` is `numpy` and `myGrid` is a numpy `array`)

```
absDiff = np.abs(myGrid - myValue)
ix = np.argmax(absDiff)
snappedValue = myGrid[ix]
```

The problem is that this approach is too slow and I need a more efficient one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import bisect
def snap(myGrid, myValue):
    ix = bisect.bisect_right(myGrid, myValue)
    if ix == 0:
        return myGrid[0]
    elif ix == len(myGrid):
        return myGrid[-1]
    else:
        return min(myGrid[ix - 1], myGrid[ix], key=lambda gridValue: abs(gridValue - myValue))
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a function for numpy arrays:

```
def ndsnap(points, grid):
    """
    Snap an 2D-array of points to values along an 2D-array grid.
    Each point will be snapped to the grid value with the smallest
    city-block distance.

    Parameters
    ---------
    points: 2D-array. Must have same number of columns as grid
    grid: 2D-array. Must have same number of columns as points

    Returns
    -------
    A 2D-array with one row per row of points. Each i-th row will
    correspond to row of grid to which the i-th row of points is closest.
    In case of ties, it will be snapped to the row of grid with the
    smaller index.
    """
    grid_3d = np.transpose(grid[:,:,np.newaxis], [2,1,0])
    diffs = np.sum(np.abs(grid_3d - points[:,:,np.newaxis]), axis=1)
    best = np.argmin(diffs, axis=1)
    return grid[best,:]
```

Answer (score 0):

In a typical case your new point will fall between two existing points in the grid. You need to use binary search to find the two points it falls between and choose the closest one out of the two. That's it.

Now all that's left is process boundary cases properly: when the points falls before first/after last and when the point hits the existing point of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Nolan Conaway's answer:

Since the Manhattan metric is being used anyway, for full, rectangular grids, the following will be faster if the grid gets large enough:

```py
def ndsnap_regular(points, *grid_axes):         
     snapped = []                                         
     for i, ax in enumerate(grid_axes):                                   
         diff = ax[:, np.newaxis] - points[:, i]
         best = np.argmin(np.abs(diff), axis=0)                                                                                                  
         snapped.append(ax[best])                                                                                           
     return np.array(snapped).T
```

Here, `grid_axes` simply contains the tuple of axis coordinates that would be used by functions such as `numpy.meshgrid` to create a grid from.

E.g. for snapping 100 3D points to a 50x50x50 grid:

```
>>> n_points = 100
>>> points = np.random.random((n_points, 3))
>>> grid = (np.linspace(0, 1), np.linspace(0, 1), np.linspace(0, 1))
>>> grid_expanded = cartesian_product(*grid)
>>> len(grid_expanded)
125000
>>> %timeit ndsnap(points, grid_expanded)
418 ms ± 3.52 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
>>> %timeit ndsnap_regular(points, *grid)
86.5 µs ± 922 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
>>> (ndsnap(points, grid_expanded) == ndsnap_regular(points, *grid)).all()
True
```